# xamarin.forms.labs ImageButton issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using **Xamarin.Forms** and a **Monodroid** project.

I use **Xamarin.Forms.Labs** to render an **ImageButton** control.

Everytime I try to render the control in xaml I get this exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Controls.ImageButton --->
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method 'BindableProperty.Create' was
>   not found.

Here is the main code of my page:

```
    <ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="*.MainPage"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Controls;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Labs">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <controls:ImageButton HeightRequest="75" WidthRequest="175" ImageHeightRequest="50" ImageWidthRequest="50"  />

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I intentionally removed the attributes to see if they were the reason of this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade xamarin.forms.labs to xlabs.forms, as the authors changed the project structure completely.

More info about this upgrade can be found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32278/upgrading-xamarin-forms-labs-to-xlabs-forms)